# How can I modify the .htaccess file so that I avoid having multiple copies of the same index.php file?

Tags: php, apache, file, .htaccess, web-development-server

I am developing an e-learning website and there is a course preview page for each course on the platform. the file structure of the platform is something like `https://example.com/courses/[course_id...]/index.php`  and the PHP code gets the course id from the parent directory name to look it up in the database. The problem here is that I have to make the same copy of the `index.php` file in each course directory I make, so is there a way to modify the `.htaccess` file in a way that I can have only one copy of the `index.php` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have a file named course.php. This file pulls up a course based on ID at a URL like:
http://localhost/course.php?id=1

In your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^courses/([0-9]+)$ course.php?id=$1
```

Then you can go to http://localhost/courses/1 to get course ID 1.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Make index.php of root

```
<?php
#For security course must exist.
# -1 will display 404
$course  = isset($_GET['course']) ? $_GET['course'] : -1;
$courses = [
    '1', '2', '3',
];
if (!in_array($course, $courses)){
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    echo '404';
    exit();
}

include_once("courses/".$course."/course.php");
```

2. Make .htaccess of root

```
RewriteEngine On
# course/x to /index.php?course=x
RewriteRule ^course/([0-9]+) /index.php?course=$1 [QSA,L]
# protect folder courses
RewriteRule ^courses/(.+)$ - [F,L]
```

3. Your directory will look like this.

```
root/
    index.php
    .htaccess
    /courses
            /1
              /course.php
            /2
              /course.php
```

```
Goto http://app.local/course/1 to /courses/1/course.php
```